# ActiveX in IE. Dialog Box not showing XP Visual Style

Tags: internet-explorer, activex, dialog, wtl, xp-theme

I have an ActiveX control in IE (7). When it shows a dialog box, the dialog box is not showing in XP visual style.  I have tried embedding manifests to no avail.  Anybody got any idea? by the way, the dialog boxes were implemented using wtl.

Comment: not sure, but seeing as how 75% of the dialogs for IE7/IE8 can't do the XP theming (and they are made by Microsoft!) I wouldn't hold out too much hope.

Answer (score 3):

Build your dll with #define ISOLATION_AWARE_ENABLED 1.
Or put compiler directive /D ISOLATION_AWARE_ENABLED=1.
Don't forget manifest should be embedded with id 2.

More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa815321%28VS.85%29.aspx#_slate_set_the_isolation_aware_enabled_directive

BTW, dialog shown from ActiveX built with these settings will be skinned even if that ActiveX is embedded into executable built without manifest.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try [Skinning a WTL dialog](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/wtl/CDialogRegionT.aspx) over on Code Project.

Answer (score 0):

I think this happens as a result of the fact that IE is reading the control exposed through COM while .NET uses it's own apprach where it reads from a manifest file.

Try calling Application.EnableVisualStyles before the form loads. That worked for me.